# How to cancel an online order and get a refund back from a U.S. service provider?

Tags: united-states, ecommerce, legal, refund

I'm from Europe and was misguided to buy a domain via GoDaddy.com's so-called Domain Buy Service, which turned out to be just the initiation of an auction service to maybe purchase the wanted domain by auction. Yes, I didn't read the Legal Agreement when doing that – I just followed the camouflaged instructions to buy a domain.

In the [Legal Agreements](http://www.godaddy.com/agreements/showdoc.aspx?pageid=Domain_Brokerage_SA&isc=webxpa) for that Domain Buy Service, there is written:

> You acknowledge and agree that in no event shall Go Daddy refund to
>   you the initial fee you are required to pay to use the Services.

Is this legit? I want to cancel the order and get my money back. What are the legal requirements to get a refund in the U.S.? What are the general, legal regulations for refundings? And least, do I have a chance of success with [GoDaddy's Legal Agreements and Policies](http://www.godaddy.com/legal-agreements.aspx?isc=webxpa&ci=46445&otab=2)?

--

EDIT: Finally got refunded by Go Daddy after filling out a support ticket at [support.godaddy.com](http://support.godaddy.com/)

Comment: How, exactly were you misguided? I'd seen the agreement some time back, and decided the service wasn't for me. I see you *didn't* read the agreement first, but you checked a box that you did. Not GD's fault. A cheap lesson to learn.

Comment: As I said, I was misguided by a camouflaged domain selling process. And I'm not the only one as I found out through search engine. Go Daddy has a policy of not allowing to delete your user account and not giving refund on some certain services. Still looks serious somehow. Yes I learned my lesson. Hope others will find out earlier.

Comment: @koivo I updated my answer with a page from GoDaddy, because their description of the Domain Buy Service (not the legal agreement, the basic description) also states clearly that they don't offer refunds. As Joe said, a cheap lesson to learn.

Comment: I don't quite understand what "camouflaged domain selling process" means. When I wanted a domain that was taken, I saw they offered this auction service. And I passed. What did it wind up costing you?

Comment: Since that service is no buying service it shouldn't be named so. It should be named "Domain Auction Service"? "Domain Buying" implies that you will take posession of a domain. But with that service you only buy the chance to maybe purchase a domain by auction, for hidden extras of course. No message informs you how that process actually will work and what additional costs or fees you have to expect. I should have read the TOS carefully. Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: It's worth a try - send a very polite email to their customer service and explain that you didn't really understand the process. The worst they can say is 'no.' In general, I've had a high success rate when I make a mistake and request a fee waiver of some kind of refund.

Comment: @koivo - HA! Excellent. I love to see when a simple suggestion solves someone's issue. You still learned a lesson (read the fine print!) but it was a free one. The best of both worlds, just a bit of aggregation. Glad to see this resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you can get a refund. In the US, companies aren't required by law to offer one. You could contact GoDaddy's customer service and ask them, but I would guess that they'll agree with the contents of the legal agreement. Unless there is another part of the agreement that *does* allow you to get a refund (there might be, I haven't read it), you're probably out of luck.

And yes, this is legitimate. It's a legal *agreement*, and by checking the box (if there was one), going through with the purchase, etc. you indicated that you read and *agreed to* the legal agreement, and therefore accepted that you wouldn't be offered a refund. GoDaddy isn't responsible if someone purchases something from them without reading the agreement before agreeing to it.

Furthermore, the legal agreement isn't the only place where the refund policy is stated. GoDaddy's page, ["What is Domain Buy Service?"](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1699/what-is-domain-buy-service) says:

> Your purchase is non-refundable and non-transferable.

This is a help page, not something you explicitly agree to (and therefore not legally binding), but as a lesson for the future, always read the description of what you're purchasing before you purchase it.

For general reference: if for some reason you were the victim of fraud, e.g. a company offered a refund in their legal agreement but refused to give it you, *and* you paid with a credit card, you have more options because you could work with your credit card company to potentially get your money back. In this case, however, the agreement was clear, so this isn't an option.